# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'CACHE_TIME' (T_STRING) in

Tags: php

My code is as below, i am getting a error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'CACHE_TIME' (T_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\intopia\settings.inc.php on line 49".

Can any one help me out, please not i am new at php.

```
<?PHP 
/**
 * Copyright 2010 Intopia.eu, All rights reserved.
 * Web: http://www.intopia.eu
 * File: STOCK parameters
 */
if (preg_match("/.inc.php/i", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) 
{
    echo "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<title>Forbidden 403</title>\r\n</head>\r\n<body><h3>Forbidden 403</h3>\r\nThe document you are requesting is forbidden.\r\n</body>\r\n</html>";
    exit;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// DATABASE
// Comment: If you want add more parameters to database parameters, 
// then change file "classes/sql.class.php"
//////////////////////////////////////////////

//Database type - REQUIRED MYSQLI
define ("DB_TYPE", "mysqlt");

define ("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define ("DB_DATABASE", "intopia");

// User must be next rights:
// ADD/UPDATE/DELETE/ALTER/CREATE VIEW/DROP VIEW
define ("DB_USERNAME", "root");
define ("DB_PASSWORD", "");

//Table prefix in database
#Example: int_
define ("PREFIX", "abk_");

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// STORE LOCATIONS
//////////////////////////////////////////////

#Example: http://www.intopia.eu/
define ("PATH_URL", "http://localhost/intopia/");

#Example: /data/main/domain/
define ("PATH_MAIN", "F:\xampp\htdocs\intopia\");

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// CACHE
// Comment: Database cache time and cache location
//////////////////////////////////////////////

define ("CACHE_TIME", "30");
define ("CACHE_URL", PATH_MAIN . "cache/");

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Comment: Date and time format (PHP & Javascripts)
//////////////////////////////////////////////

define ("DATE_FORMAT", "d.m.Y"); //PHP scripts
define ("DATE_FORMAT_JS", "dd.mm.yyyy"); //Javascripts

define ("TIME_FORMAT", "H:i"); //PHP scripts
define ("TIME_FORMAT_JS", "hh:mm"); //Javascripts

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// VIEW LOCK
// Comment: How long time view locked in minutes 
//////////////////////////////////////////////

define ("VIEW_LOCKED_TIME", "5");

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// FILE UPLOAD AND LOCATION
//////////////////////////////////////////////

//How big can be file on upload 1 000 000 = 1 MB
define ("UPLOAD_FILE_MAX_SIZE", "4000000");

//Delete uploaded file permanently or let to uploaded catalog
define ("DELETE_UPLOAD_PERMANENTLY", true);

//Stock upload file location
define ("DOCUMENT_PATH_MAIN", PATH_MAIN."document/");

?>
```

Comment: Syntax highlighting gives it away pretty clearly.

Answer (score 2):

```
define ("PATH_MAIN", "F:\xampp\htdocs\intopia\");
```

You need to escape the last backslash, the one right before the closing quote.

Change it so it becomes

```
define ("PATH_MAIN", "F:\xampp\htdocs\intopia\\");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
define ("PATH_MAIN", "F:\xampp\htdocs\intopia\");
```

All backslashes must be escaped in double-quoted strings:

```
define ("PATH_MAIN", "F:\\xampp\\htdocs\\intopia\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

please use \ in below line

```
define ("PATH_MAIN", "F:\xampp\htdocs\intopia\\");
```